# Which IDE is better for roscpp autocompletion/suggestion?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to learn the ros programming by looking the suggestions,
I use ros kinetic,

- /rosdistro: kinetic
- /rosversion: 1.12.14

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343417/which-ide-is-better-for-roscpp-autocompletion/suggestion?/) by [amanuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/51521/amanuel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-02-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-06**:
I suggest to take a look at the [wiki/IDEs](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs) page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I personally use VS Code and I am happy with it. Note that you need to install a few of extensions and clang for auto complete to be working properly.

```
C/C++ Clang Command Adapter
```

can be installed freely from market place of VS Code. You also need to create a .vscode folder under root folder of your project, which will have proper setting files, as an example you can refer to link below and adjust the oaths according to your system,

[link](https://github.com/jediofgever/ROS_Raw_Kitti_Player/tree/master/.vscode)

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2020-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thazz](https://answers.ros.org/users/39841/thazz/) on 2020-02-07**:
I also use VS Code and I like. You can also check [this post](https://erdalpekel.de/?p=157) with instructions how to use VS Code with ROS.

**Comment by [amanuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/51521/amanuel/) on 2020-02-08**:
Hello, thank you. I edited the "c_cpp_properties.json" fiile as you suggested and replaced your "/home/atas/catkin_ws/src/ROS_Raw_Kitti_Player/kitti_ros/include" by my ws "/home/fele/catkin_ws/src/basics/include"
and other all in the path [ ] and it works now!!! thanks